# Would the following question be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic

Alright, I wonder whether a question like the following would be deemed on-topic. I am posting below the question as it would appear on the actual site.

> The opening credits for episodes of TV series "Masters of Sex"
>   pictures what is apparently supposed to be sexual innuendo. The
>   imagery in sequence contains (where unsure I added a question mark):
>
> - a sunflower blossoming in time lapse
> - a cock (the animal)
> - a railway tunnel
> - the Washington Memorial
> - a cat being pet
> - a knife buttering a muffin
> - a blouse being opened (?)
> - a lady biting into an apple
> - a beaver munching on a twig
> - a coin being inserted into a slot
> - some kind of cream/balm being pushed out of a tube (container) and wiped off with a finger
> - a mushroom (fungus) growing
> - a torero tricking a bull with a red cloth
> - a train driving into a railway tunnel
> - a Venus flytrap entrapping a fly
> - cream being applied to a spatula (?)
> - bread rolls inflating in an oven (?)
> - a key inserted into a lock
> - a cucumber being washed under running water
> - a billiard ball being sunk into a pocket
> - pinball machine kicking a ball
> - "male" bunny figurine behind "female" bunny figurine "humping" (?)
> - a switch labeled "Vibrate" being switched on
> - a patch being applied to an arm (?) to fixate some electrode (?)
> - a thermometer going beyond safe limits (according to a label)
> - a blinking advert with the label "BINGO"
> - a wine bottle being uncorked
> - a person dropping a gown (?)
> - a champagne bottle being popped open and some foam escaping
> - some wires being dragged across a belly (?)
> - a lie detector or cardiogram or similar
> - a balloon containing confetti being popped
> - a bed sheet clenched by a female and a male hand respectively
> - a geyser going off
> - a rocket being launched
> - a firework igniting
> - a volcano erupting
> - two feet caressing each other then toes "clenching"
> - a firework (?)
> - a neck area
> - a blossom opening in time lapse
>
> Some are obvious to me, e.g. the phallic symbols. However, even those
>   and certainly the others probably require knowledge about slang use for
>   certain words (e.g. I think at some point I heard *beaver* being used
>   for the vagina or that area).
>
> Unfortunately, I presume, it takes some native speaker of English
>   living in a particular culture given the origin of the series
>   (probably US-American?).
>
> Would someone please be so kind as to point out the proverbial/slang
>   sayings attached to the imagery?!

And yeah, I am serious about this question. This is not meant as a practical joke but genuine interest in the proverbial sayings or slang words that are behind the imagery.

I've been to the US and other parts of the world where English is a first language. However, since dictionaries rarely ever list these words (possible exception the Urban Dictionary - which has no reverse search, though) and there is a sometimes eerie sense of political correctness at the office, it's hard to learn these things. I was luckier with Russian (which is neither my native language) in the past (more "informal" encounters than formal ones).

Thanks for your input.

Comment: I'm tempted to say "What?! Are you nuts?, so I won't. Instead, I'll say that the question is on topic, but  It's far far far too long. It would be unrealistic to expect users to supply an answer for each and every single image=euphemism. I'd suggest to select three, max, and do a little research, share that info and then "Bob's your uncle". I think it could turn out to be a very interesting fun question, if presented well.

Comment: I'm sorry but how can you *not* understand the meaning behind a blouse being unbuttoned, and someone's dress (gown) falling to the ground? People often get undressed before doing a little *nooky* :) BTW I've not seen the series, is it tacky?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I already wrote that for some of those I *can* understand or at least guess what the imagery refers to. But the problem is: not for all. Also, the reason I present a full list is simply because there's a good chance I misunderstood parts that I thought to have understood. Something like the blouse could refer to slang or be a straight to the point reference of the obvious. I don't find it tacky, no. But it is the dramatization of a cooperation that actually took place (you probably know the Kinsey report better than the name Masters).

Comment: Post a question asking users to check FORTY phrases, and the post will be closed immediately. That's all I'm saying.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: got it, thanks! I guess then I'll leave it unasked for now.

Comment: Note that questions on this site must be about **language**. Non-linguistic symbols, even when used in an Anglo culture, are off-topic.

Comment: The only really linguistic feature of that list is the one about a beaver, which you have already answered. All the others are entirely visual (and fairly obvious).

Comment: @AndrewLeach: awesome comment, that doubles as answer to my question. Thanks.

Comment: @curiousdannii: now this is why I asked here first. My issue is that I can't know already what I don't know already. Logically I have to go by *some* premise. So I asked on the suspicion that there's more than meets the eye in the imagery and that they refer to some kind of slang. If it's purely visual references: fine. In that sense the comments answered my question. The catch 22 here, however, is that I had to go by *some* assumption, since I did not know it either way ;)